# Accordion scrolls to the top of page when opened or closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm quite new to web development and i tried making an accordion.
Now everything seems to work the only problem is that if I have content above the accordion it keeps scrolling to the top of the page. I just can't seem to grasp why its not working.

```js
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-heading");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  elem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      let active = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".panel-container .panel-heading.active"
      );
      for (let j = 0; j < active.length; j++) {
        active[j].classList.remove("active");
        active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.43;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #123274;
}

.panel-container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel-heading {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #123274;
  border: 1px solid #123274;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.panel-heading:hover {
  background-color: #f8f9fb;
}

.panel-heading:after {
  content: "\002B";
  color: #123274;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.random {
  height: 60vh;
  color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <body>
    <div class="random"></div>
    <div class="panel-container">
      <h1>Accordion met iconen</h1>

      <a href="#" class="panel-heading">Sectie 1</a>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="panel-heading">Sectie 2</a>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="panel-heading">Sectie 3</a>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-container">
      <h1>Accordion #2 met iconen</h1>

      <a href="#" class="panel-heading">Sectie 1</a>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="panel-heading">Sectie 2</a>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="panel-heading">Sectie 3</a>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I hope someone can help me with this issue,

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Try removing the `href="#"` from the `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<a></a>` tag is basically a link, it's supposed to take you places, if you linked it `#` then you linked it to your root, which is basically the same page. Try changing to a different html tag instead. I used `div` in the below snippet, check it for your reference.

```js
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName("panel-heading");
let i;

for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  elem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    let panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      let active = document.querySelectorAll(
        ".panel-container .panel-heading.active"
      );
      for (let j = 0; j < active.length; j++) {
        active[j].classList.remove("active");
        active[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.43;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #123274;
}

.panel-container {
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.panel-heading {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #123274;
  border: 1px solid #123274;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active,
.panel-heading:hover {
  background-color: #f8f9fb;
}

.panel-heading:after {
  content: "\002B";
  color: #123274;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.random {
  height: 60vh;
  color: blue;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <body>
    <div class="random"></div>
    <div class="panel-container">
      <h1>Accordion met iconen</h1>

      <div class="panel-heading">Sectie 1</div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading">Sectie 2</div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading">Sectie 3</div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-container">
      <h1>Accordion #2 met iconen</h1>

      <div class="panel-heading">Sectie 1</div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading">Sectie 2</div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-heading">Sectie 3</div>
      <div class="panel">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This seemed to work, thanks alot for the clear explanation, here is was just looking around in the js forever haha.

Comment: @tomtom500 If your question was answered correctly, please accept that answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.